# Removed Python in order to update Linux Mint and now cannot get in

Tags: python, linux, boot, linux-mint

I just wanted to go from 2.7 to 3.5+. To do that I did

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python
```

Followed by installing python 3.5 packages..

Now I cannot get into my operating system. It shows the screen for UBuntu 13.04 but beyond that it restarts. How do I go about recovering my Linux Mint back?

Do I need to reinstall it fresh or is there way to repair this. Please help me out.

Comment: **Don't. Ever. Remove. System. Programs.** Python 2 and 3 can live happily next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely need to reinstall fresh. You can view the Ubuntu wiki on Python [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python). Essentially, a lot of base packages have dependencies upon Python 2.7. A potentially more thorough response is available over on AskUbuntu at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/315018).

As also mentioned by other users, the preferred method is to install Python 3 alongside Python 2. It's easy enough to invoke it by using `python3` instead of `python`.

Answer (score 1):

As per @MattDMo, I did have a USB Stick with Linux Mint 17.3 (the latest copy) and over wrote the already installed copy of Linux Mint. It worked like a charm!

Two things to keep a note of:
1.) Do not install a lower version than the one that is/was present because that does not work well.
2.) Your home folder is not encrypted, if it is it will be an interesting problem.

Also AFAIK there is no need to reinstall fresh, you can just install the copy in the same drive and location and it should work fine.